# Using recursion to find the trace of gamma matrices

Tags: list-manipulation, functions, recursion, scoping

All you need to know about the gamma matrices for this problem is that there are four of them, $\gamma_{\mu}$ with $\mu = 0, 1, 2, 3$, and that the trace of the product of n gamma matrices (n even) obeys the following recursive relation:

[image]

Here, $\widehat{\gamma}_{\nu_k}$ signifies absence of $\gamma_{\nu_k}$ and $g_{\nu_1,\nu_k}$ is a tensor with two indices.(BTW, when n is odd the result is zero). Here's my attempt at the code:

```
TrGamma[z__] :=
If[Length[z] == 2, 
  4*Subscript[g, z[[1]], z[[2]]] ,

  (*Else*)
  Module[ {x = 0, n = Length[z]},
     For[i = 2, i <= n, i++,
       Module[{y = Delete[z, {{1}, {i}}]},
       x = x + (-1)^i*Subscript[g, z[[1]], z[[i]]]*TrGamma[y]]
     ];
   x
  ]
]
```

This gives the correct answer for n=2 and n=4:

```
In[4]:= TrGamma[{Subscript[\[Nu], 1],Subscript[\[Nu], 2]}]
TrGamma[{Subscript[\[Nu], 1],Subscript[\[Nu], 2],Subscript[\[Nu],3],Subscript[\[Nu], 4]}]
```

Output:

[image]

[image]

However, when I try n = 6 or higher it just keeps running. I'm guess there's something about Module that I'm missing or have misunderstood. I've tried replacing Module with Block and the problem still persists.

Comment: You might be interested in ``Internal`DiracGammaMatrix[]``: ``Table[Internal`DiracGammaMatrix[k], {k, 5}]``.

Comment: Or you could study the source code of  [DiracTrace](https://feyncalc.github.io/FeynCalcBook/ref/DiracTrace.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the formula has a sum ($\sum$), it's best to use `Sum`:

```
TrGamma[nu1_, nu2_] := 4 Subscript[g, nu1, nu2]

TrGamma[indices___] := 
  Sum[
    (-1)^k Subscript[g, {indices}[[1]], {indices}[[k]]] * 
    TrGamma @@ Delete[{indices}, {{1}, {k}}],
  {k, 2, Length[{indices}]}]
```

Comment: Tried it and it works!

Comment: @Feynmaniac Ok, don't forget to upvote this and other answers if you found them helpful.  Mark it as accepted if it answers your question.

Comment: Right. Sorry, I'm new here.

Answer (score 0):

Are you just trying to understand how to get recursion working in Mathematica, or are you mainly interested in having some useful functions for dealing with gamma matrices?  If the latter, there is a package GAMMA by Ulf Gran which will handle all your gamma matrix needs, in any dimension and in any signature:

https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0105086

Comment: I'm interested in both, actually. I'll check out the package.

Comment: @Feynmaniac Depending on what you want to do, you may find [FeynCalc](https://feyncalc.github.io) quite useful.